# Bootstrap: How do I keep the navigation from truncating?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am working on a Bootstrap 3 site and have everything working except the main menu. It has a hair trigger when it comes to resizing and truncates well in advance of the overall page sizing and quickly drops the last two navigation items to the next row, disrupting the slider, before it adjusts to the mobile navigation.

The page can be found [here](http://jackson.opteradev.com). 
The HTML is as follows:

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
                </div><!-- navbar-header -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#attorneys">Our Attorneys</a></li>
            <li><a href="#business-litigation">Business Ligitagion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#business-litigation">Personal Injury</a></li>
            <li><a href="#business-litigation">Verdicts &amp; Settlements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#business-litigation">Client Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#business-litigation">Map &amp; Directions</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- navbar -->
```

The CSS:

```
/* @group navigation */

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #9d2024;
  border: none;
  height: 25px;

}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar-default { 
    min-height:50px;     
} 
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  font-family: trebuchet ms;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:last-child > a { 
    border: none; 
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #9d2024;
}
```

If I remove the container the navigation floats to the far left and does not flow with the page. I could use some insight for getting the navigation to resize properly without truncating.

Comment: you either get rid of some menu elements or use `font-size:9px !important;` (yes, this is the exact size you need if you want to have only one line while keeping responsive behavior), there's no other way it doesn't truncate

Comment: So are you trying to switch to the mobile drop-down navigation earlier? Or are you trying to make those two navigation items flow with the page? Obviously they simply won't fit in one line unless the font size and spacing is reduced.

Comment: I would like to keep it until it gets to the mobile navigation. One problem I see it a large space at the right side of the navigation that acts like padding, but there isn't anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need yo use right bootstrap structure.

Problem is here:

`row banner`and `row slider-bg` divs classes. Just remove `row` name and all need to work.

Error reason of start building a bootstrap is put a row of parent of `container` class. Container is first wrapping class in bootstrap, then comes `row` and then `cols`

For menu use smaller font size or inner `li, a` paddings.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I removed 'row' from both divs and it removed the horizontal scrollbar, however, the navigation still truncates. Am I missing something else?

Comment: There is just not for enought space to show last menu item. You can  make a font size smaller or make inner padding lower. `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {padding: 3px 7px;}`

Comment: The combination of removing the 'row' and reducing the font size did it. Thank you!